# Determining if a Pandas dataframe row has multiple specific values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas data frame represented by the one below:

```
     A    B    C    D
 |   1    1    1    3    |
 |   1    1    1    2    |
 |   2    3    4    5    |
```

I need to iterate through this data frame, looking for rows where the values in columns A, B, & C match and if that's true check the values in column D for those rows and delete the row with the smaller value.  So, in above example would look like this afterwards.

```
         A    B    C    D
    |    1    1    1    3    |
    |    2    3    4    5    |
```

I've written the following code, but something isn't right and it's causing an error.  It also looks more complicated than it may need to be, so I am wondering if there is a better, more concise way to write this.

```
 for col, row in df.iterrows():
...     df1 = df.copy()
...     df1.drop(col, inplace = True)
...     for col1, row1 in df1.iterrows():
...             if df[0].iloc[col] == df1[0].iloc[col1] & df[1].iloc[col] == df1[1].iloc[col1] & 
                df[2].iloc[col] == df1[2].iloc[col1] & df1[3].iloc[col1] > df[3].iloc[col]:
...                     df.drop(col, inplace = True)
```

Comment: is this what you are after : ``df.groupby(["A", "B", "C"], as_index=False).max()``?

Answer (score 1):

You can groupby all the variables (using `groupby(['A', 'B', 'C'])`) which  have to be equal and then exclude the row with minimum value of D (using `func)`) if there are multiple unique records to get the boolean indices for the rows which has to be retained

```
def func(x):
    if len(x.unique()) != 1:
        return x != x.min()
    else:
        return x == x

df[df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C'])['D'].apply(lambda x: func(x))]
    
    A   B   C   D
0   1   1   1   3
2   2   3   4   5
```

If row having just the maximum group value in `D` has to be retained. Then you can use the below:

```
df[df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C'])['D'].apply(lambda x: x == x.max())]
```

Comment: This is not correct. The row with the minimum value of 'D' must be removed. For group [1,1,1] min value is 2

Comment: Read the question wrongly. Corrected the answer

Comment: Thank you for your help.  When I ran this with the random data that I provided above it worked.  However for some reason this didn't work on the actual data I'm working with.   I verified that the values in columns a, b, and c matched, respectively and that the values in 'd' entered the first step of the if statement in func.  I then confirmed that the larger value is what is being returned but then nothing appears to have changed in the final data frame.  Any idea what might be happening and how to possibly fix?

Comment: @HelpWithR if you can replicate the issue with again some random data, that would be great.

Comment: @HelpWithR just to confirm out of curiosity, you have to delete only the group row where `D` value is minimum?

Comment: It should actually be deleting ALL rows but the one with the maximum value in D as there could be multiple matches.  Also, for data.  Column A and B both contain normal strings.  Nothing special.    Column C and D both contain pandas timestamps in the form "2019-09-30 00:00:00" (Columns C and D have no relation other than being the same data type) .  To add to the confusion, when I do this through a powershell, it works. But for some reason when I run the script this is a part of,  I can tell that the values match and that the function runs, but then it doesn't remove any rows afterwards.

Comment: The actual dataset contains around 60 rows of data with several of the rows matching another row, but most have no matches.  Not sure how this could be relevant, but just in case.

Comment: I have editted the answer for just retaining the row having maximum group value in `D`

Comment: Still not producing the results I need.   It's copied word for word (other than changing the names of the columns) so I'm stumped as to what could be wrong.  How about pulling the index of the row(s) to be deleted and then simply drop them from the data frame?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227090/discussion-between-ggaurav-and-helpwithr).

Comment: @ggaurav - I'll be in chat for a little while.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution:

```
df[~((df[['A', 'B', 'C']].duplicated(keep=False)) & (df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C'])['D'].transform(min)==df['D']))]
```

Explanation:

```
df[['A', 'B', 'C']].duplicated(keep=False)
```

returns a mask for rows with duplicated values of ['A', 'B', 'C'] columns

```
df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C'])['D'].transform(min)==df['D']
```

returns a mask for rows that have the minimum value for ['D'] column, for each group of ['A', 'B', 'C']

The combination of these masks, selects all these rows (duplicated ['A', 'B', 'C'] and minimum 'D' for the group. With ~ we select all other rows except from these ones.

Result for the provided input:

```
   A  B  C  D
0  1  1  1  3
2  2  3  4  5
```